# Gibberish Sound Effect

Tags: lego-games

I am now creating my first LEGO stop motion animation with sound effects.

I do not want to use a specific language for them speaking. Instead, I am using subtitles. For the talking sound effect, I would like to use the gibberish sound effect that is used in some LEGO-sponsored video games.

I have looked around the web for hours now trying to find this sound effect and, sadly, cannot find it anywhere. Does anybody know where I can find this sound effect?

Does anybody know how I can maybe recreate it?

Comment: I don't suppose you could upload a clip to YouTube or something so we can hear the exact sound?  Which LEGO sponsored video games exactly?

Comment: @brandaemon - Gandalf 'talking'; http://youtu.be/ghUZUpN9rks; 0:38

Comment: If you want I can post this as an answer, but I don't think it's a stock sound effect.  Rather, Traveler's Tales records mumbling/grunting gibberish as its style of minifigure speech.  I'd recommend taking a microphone and just making up your own sounds for your animation.

Comment: Have a look at Brotherhood Workshop, he manages to create a type of gibberish talking by simply mangling how he speaks English

Comment: @Dopapp You won't find Gandalf in a Harry Potter game

Comment: @brandaemon - could you please add your comment as an answer? It solved my question.

Comment: @Dopapp this may clear the confusion: https://youtu.be/nGR8EHL6nkI

Answer (score 4):

There is no one gibberish sound effect for LEGO minifigures.

[Traveler's Tales](http://www.ttgames.com/) (the developer of many popular LEGO video games) creates its cutscenes with a mime/sound effect style similar to [movies found on the LEGO website](http://www.lego.com/en-us/starwars/movies/movies/the-han-solo-affair).  Rather than record character voices with words (as Warner Brothers did with *[The LEGO Movie](https://youtu.be/fZ_JOBCLF-I)*) Traveler's Tales recorded voice actors to mimic gibberish murmuring, grunting, and other non-lexical sounds.

If you would like to emulate this filmmaking style, I suggest you use a microphone of your own and record the sounds yourself.  Have fun!

Comment: This is not as hard as it sounds. I made a movie with my kids. I was responsible for holding the camera and doing engine sounds. In one scene we had a car, a helicpter and a motor cycle at the same time. The result was quite impressive with only a little adjustments of loudness and panning of the different sound tracks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking for speaking sound recordings on free sound effect websites, like [this one](http://www.sounddogs.com/extendedsearch.asp?keyword=man%20speaking&ddCategory=-1). You might use foreign languages too, those have an additional layer of realism over an indiscernible muttering, provide a nice easter egg if they really mean something (just make sure they aren't offensive :D)

Comment: My hovercraft is full of eels!